# hide border-top in center of div

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is what I am trying to achieve

[image: half circle]

This is in my `div`'s open state so normally you do not see any filters but instead just a full circle. What I am having trouble with is I dont know how to prevent a border on a small section.

Here is what I have below as well as a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/XpJNxO)

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bp-purple {
  color: #9696ff;
}

.bp-nyan {
  color: #67cfd6;
}

.bp-pink {
  color: #e49092;
}

.bp-green {
  color: #96cf6b;
}

.filter-options {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.filter-options__intro {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  color: #222;
}
.filter-options__intro i {
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
  display: block;
}
.filter-options__intro:hover {
  color: #f93;
}
.filter-options__selections {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 -25px 0;
}
.filter-options__selections .list-inline, .filter-options__selections .checkbox {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.filter-options__selections input {
  margin: 0;
}
.filter-options__selections .first {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.filter-options__selections .dotted-line {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="filter-options">
  <a href="" class="filter-options__intro">
   <b class="center-block">Filters</b>
   <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="filter-options__selections clearfix">
   <div class="clearfix">
    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
     <li class="first bp-purple">Categories:</li>
     <li>Category 1</li>
     <li>Category 2</li>
     <li>Category 3</li>
     <li>Category 4</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="pull-right bold" href="">View All <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </div>
   <div class="dotted-line"></div>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
     <li class="first bp-nyan">Location:</li>
     <li>Shanghai</li>
     <li>Beijing</li>
     <li>Hangzhou</li>
     <li>Chengdu</li>
     <li>Guangzhou</li>
     <li>Shenzhen</li>
     <li>Suzhou</li>
     <li>Nanjing</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="pull-right bold" href="">View All <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </div>
   <div class="dotted-line"></div>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
     <li class="first bp-pink">Brand:</li>
     <li>Belle</li>
     <li>St&amp;Sat</li>
     <li>Charles &amp; Keith</li>
     <li>Aldo</li>
     <li>Daphne</li>
     <li>Zara</li>
     <li>Camel</li>
     <li>Le Saunda</li>
     <li>Tata</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="pull-right bold" href="">View All <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </div>
   <div class="dotted-line"></div>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
     <li class="first bp-green">Price Range:</li>
     <li>100 - 200</li>
     <li>200 - 500</li>
     <li>500 - 1000</li>
     <li>1000 - 3000</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="dotted-line"></div>
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
              <input type="checkbox" /> Show only free shipping products
            </label>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
              <input type="checkbox" /> Do not show international products
            </label>
   </div>
   <div class="dotted-line"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** 
Added sass tag as my codepen is in sass but not sure if stack lets me use it in snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make `<a>` position relatively.

```
.filter-options__intro {
 position: relative;
}
```

Then add an css after selector, to cover up the black line

```
a.filter-options__intro:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1111;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Working example:
[Overlap element using CSS :after](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/BpypBw)

Comment: @PraveenKumar see my example

Comment: Strangely, it works for you. But I gave the same code, it didn't work. Anyway, I tried something else, check out mine.

Comment: I have updated my pen to be compatible with your scss, see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks this one seems to work the best with my current structure

Answer (score 1):

Tried something that might help you:

- Position the whole DOM of the link `relative`.
- I had to use three DOM Elements to make it look like your output.
- Positioned the content at `z-index: 1`.
- Positioned others in higher `z-index`.
- Gave a faux background.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.faux-cutter {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -2px;
}
.border {
  padding: 10px 20px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="faux-cutter">
    <a href="" class="border">Hi</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  Content here.
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

I would layer the semi-circle over the rectangle, and then I would add an inner absolutely positioned div to hide the bottom of the filters circle. You could do something like this:

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.bp-purple {
  color: #9696ff;
}
.bp-nyan {
  color: #67cfd6;
}
.bp-pink {
  color: #e49092;
}
.bp-green {
  color: #96cf6b;
}
.filter-options {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.filter-options__intro {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: white;
  padding: 30px 0;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  color: #222;
}
.filter-options__intro i {
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
  display: block;
}
.filter-options__intro:hover {
  color: #f93;
}
.filter-options__selections {
  border-top: 1px solid #222;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
}
.filter-options__selections-inner {
  position:absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  background: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
.filter-options__selections .list-inline,
.filter-options__selections .checkbox {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.filter-options__selections input {
  margin: 0;
}
.filter-options__selections .first {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.filter-options__selections .dotted-line {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="filter-options">
    <a href="" class="filter-options__intro">
      <b class="center-block">Filters</b>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="filter-options__selections clearfix">
      <div class="filter-options__selections-inner">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
            <li class="first bp-purple">Categories:</li>
            <li>Category 1</li>
            <li>Category 2</li>
            <li>Category 3</li>
            <li>Category 4</li>
          </ul>
          <a class="pull-right bold" href="">View All <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dotted-line"></div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
            <li class="first bp-nyan">Location:</li>
            <li>Shanghai</li>
            <li>Beijing</li>
            <li>Hangzhou</li>
            <li>Chengdu</li>
            <li>Guangzhou</li>
            <li>Shenzhen</li>
            <li>Suzhou</li>
            <li>Nanjing</li>
          </ul>
          <a class="pull-right bold" href="">View All <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dotted-line"></div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
            <li class="first bp-pink">Brand:</li>
            <li>Belle</li>
            <li>St&amp;Sat</li>
            <li>Charles &amp; Keith</li>
            <li>Aldo</li>
            <li>Daphne</li>
            <li>Zara</li>
            <li>Camel</li>
            <li>Le Saunda</li>
            <li>Tata</li>
          </ul>
          <a class="pull-right bold" href="">View All <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dotted-line"></div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
            <li class="first bp-green">Price Range:</li>
            <li>100 - 200</li>
            <li>200 - 500</li>
            <li>500 - 1000</li>
            <li>1000 - 3000</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="dotted-line"></div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Show only free shipping products
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />Do not show international products
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="dotted-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a portion of the border. I'd suggest adding a span to mask that particular part of the border with a small rectangular shape and z-index. [Here is a forked pen with my changes.](http://codepen.io/emilymentrek/pen/bgNgba)

I added a `span` with the class of 'mask' directly within your `.filter-options` div. `<span class="mask"></span>`.

Adding some CSS allowed me to build the shape of the mask using a solid white block. It will work as long as the background color remains white.

```
.mask {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 77px;            
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
 }
```